# Parse WMIC output to set returned value as a variable (windows batch)

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I have the following command:

```
c:\wmic baseboard get Manufacturer
Manufacturer
ASUSTeK Computer INC.
```

I'd like to save it's output into variable and process some way like I did it with bash here: [esxi_hwinfo.sh @ GitHub](https://github.com/maaboo/AdminTools/blob/master/esxi_hwinfo.sh) e.g.: remove some sub-strings, shorten numbers, convert one string to another etc.

Is it possible to iterate over lines inside variable and get for instance the second one? Examples which I've seen work only with files (`for /f "delims=" %%1 in ('type !foo!') do`). If I use variable instead of file it says that there is no such file.

I don't want to use files as intermediaries since I think it's generally a bad idea.

There is no problem code which I want to work. There is a question about technical implementation (or possibility) of what I'm trying to achieve. It's more like "how to" than "what's wrong" question (like the most in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file?sort=votes&pageSize=15))

Comment: You've only provided half a question, you need to show us what you've tried to do with the multi-line variable and where it failed to do what you intended or expected.

Comment: I write here and if it's acceptable I'll edit the original post. I have the command with multi-line output like `wmic baseboard get Manufacturer` I have to extract needed line, parse it (depends on kind of value) and generate new output. I thought that original question is more general since there could be some other situations which require multi-line variables that's why I tried to avoid answering to that particular case.

Comment: Please add the content of `outputted.txt` to your question after running `WMIC /Output:outputted.txt Baseboard Get Manufacturer`. Also we do need to see your problem code, posting a question with pretend information is unlikely to return a working solution!

Comment: Totally rewrote question, hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set "manu="&for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%m in ('wmic baseboard get manufacturer') do if not defined manu set "manu=%%m"

rem now do things to %manu%
echo %manu%
pause
```